# Problema com WordPress e conexão com MySQL.

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Tudo bem pessoal

Desenvolvi um portal de noticias para empresa que eu trabalho e neste portal tenho uma media de 500 mil acessos mês.

Estou tendo a algum tempo muitos problemas com meu site.

O mesmo tem uma base dados enorme (4GB) pois tem noticias desde de 2010.
Quando se posta uma matéria relevante que tem muitos acessos simultâneos o mesmo da erro de banco de dados.

Hoje eu tentei usar o MySQL do Google cloud servidas. Migrei a base de dados é virei o site para conectar nesta base no Google.
Só que ficou pior hora aves dava hora dava erro de banco de dados.
No mesmo servidor eu coloquei uma conexão simples de banco de dados em PHP para testar a conexão e quando o wordpress informava erro de conexão no banco o script php conectava normalmente.

O que pode está acontecendo?
No Google cloud não estava ocorrendo nenhuma sobrecarga

Comment: Qual erro especificamente você está tendo? A partir de quantos acessos simultâneos mais ou menos o banco começa a dar esse erro?

Comment: Em torno de uns 800 acessos simultâneos. Mas já tive problemas com menos ... Hoje quando testei o MySQL do google cloud nem foi preciso isso, com muito menos acessos dava erro de conexão com banco de dados

Comment: Você tem um log de quais queries estão sendo feitas a cada acesso? É muito provável que você tenha uma ou duas consultas muito ineficientes que estão se tornando o gargalo ai. 800 acessos não devia derrubar um servidor.

Comment: Se não tiver acesso pelo MySQL, instale esse plugin e pegue a lista das queries que são geradas quando você acessa um artigo: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/

Comment: Tenho no meu tema consultas para montar este tema.
Varias consultas estão gastando 1.316,6ms (1.31656813622s).

Nestas consultas eu obtenho posts diferentes  (com a clausula not IN)

Comment: Usar NOT IN e subqueries em geral já reduz bastante a eficiência das consultas, tem várias perguntas no SOen e outros sites a respeito 1,3s para cada consulta é impraticável.